# Wordpress Theme's 404.php not found, server defaults to Apache's own 404 page

Tags: 404-error, apache

if I just type something to provoke a 404 Error on my Wordpress installation, Wordpress doesn't load its own 404.php file, but the Apache server's own 404 error message gets displayed.

### What is wrong with my Wordpress installation? Do I need to edit the Apache server's config file and redirect to the Wordpress 404.php page?

UPDATE:

I have partially managed to get this working, I missed the `FileInfo` directive in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file. Not all stuff get caught gracefully, though.

Comment: Most of the time WordPress can do what you ask automatically. What is the address of a working page? And the address you are using that returns the wrong 404? Is this multisite?

Comment: Are you using pretty permalinks? And have you checked that `mod_rewrite` is enabled & the correct rules are in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: My installations is at 192.168.1.8/wordpress/ That's the front page of my site. I submit something like 192.168.1.8/wordpress/asdasdasd and then get redirected to the Apache servers's 404 error message page.

Comment: I have the default permalink style selected, eg. http://192.168.1.8/wordpress/?p=123

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Where do I check mod_rewrite and .htaccess?

Comment: @user261562 : with default permalinks you don't need `mod_rewrite` or `.htaccess`, but that is kinda the problem. Let me verify and I will post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things are working the way they are supposed to, and possibly the only way they *can* work. Let me explain.

Without an Apache module called [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (or the equivalent Nginx or IIS component) requests to PHP pages have to go to an actual filesystem file. That is what you see with requests like `192.168.1.8/wordpress/?p=123`. The file being accessed is the [directory "index" file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)-- `index.php`. That request is the equivalent of `192.168.1.8/wordpress/index.php?p=123`. What you are doing is requesting some other file/directory with requests like this one-- `192.168.1.8/wordpress/asdasdasd`-- and no such file or directory exists in the filesystem.

With `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` properly configured ***all requests*** get sent to `index.php`. [Take a look at the stock WordPress `.htaccess` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That `RewriteRule` pushes everything (almost everything) to `index.php`. That allows WordPress to process *any* request, even requests for files that don't physically exist on the system.

Without pretty permalinks enabled-- that is, with the "default" permalinks selected-- WordPress will not even try to parse the requests so that is equivalent to not having `mod_rewrite` or `.htaccess` at all.

And, if WordPress can't parse the request, WordPress can't load the theme's `404.php`. Apache, of course, still knows the request is bad and loads its own 404 message.

So, without `mod_rewrite`, a proper `.htaccess` file, and pretty permalinks you get the behavior you describe, which is exactly how things are supposed to work.

Comment: I have enabled mod_rewrite with `a2enmode rewrite` and created the .htaccess file with the sample content on the Wordpress>Using Permalinks page, but it's still not working out properly. I have noticed that if request server/wordpress/index (no .php) it will redirect to the custom Wordpress 404 page but not if I request something gibberish.

Comment: By the way, the .htaccess file is in the /var/www/wordpress/ folder is that correct?

Comment: `.htaccess` should be in the same directory as `wp-load.php` usually. That looks right.

Comment: Well, I am out of clues, what could be messing up this, I guess having all the files in the subdirectory of /var/wwww/ is not a good idea to host Wordpress. But thanks any way, I will accept your answer as the best, since you have put a lot of effort in this and hope that future users will find it useful in fixing their problem.

Comment: hmmm... something is weird with your setup and I don't know what.

Comment: Yeah, something is suspicious, I will try a clean reinstall.

Comment: Servers default to different server root directories but there should be no reason you can't run WordPress from a subdirectory. I do all the time.

Comment: "even requests for files that don't physically exist on the system" - technically, the rules *only* rewrite in this case, hence the `RewriteCond`'s :)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic : yes, good point.

Answer (score 5):

WordPress will only handle 404's if pretty permalinks are enabled - go to Settings > Permalinks and choose one of the options other than default (or use your own).

Comment: I have checked 3 (Day and name, Numeric and Post name) and this doesn't seem to have an effect, i.e. I still get the Apache 404 error message not the 404.php. I am using the Twenty Thirteen theme, by the way.

Comment: Check out @s_ha_dum's answer, it'll explain things *much* better!