# How is WordPress manipulating the posts like there are folders?

Tags: php, posts, permalinks, urls

As you know, a WordPress post can usually be seen going to a link similar to this:

```
myblog.com/2014/03/27/sample-post/
```

There is no folder named `2014`, `03`, `27` or `sample-post` in the blog.

Until now, I used something like this: `page.php?post_id=55`.

How is WordPress and other sites (I think StackExchange sites do this too) doing this?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but I think it explains things nonetheless: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139271/21376

Comment: So it's a type of 404 error? And the 404 page takes the current like link (`2014/03/27`)? If this is how it works, than why wordpress is working on localhost without any `.htdocs` file there?

Comment: No, it isn't a 404 error. That question is asking about 404 errors but in explaining that I more or less explained how WordPress URL rewriting works in general.

Comment: Oh, now i got it. So i need the `mod_rewrite` ?

Comment: I think i found the answer here: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite . but how is wordpress setting this up when i install it?

Comment: Yes, you will need `mod_rewrite`. WordPress doesn't set up `mod_rewrite`. That has to be installed on the server. WordPress will use it (or try to) if you enable pretty permalinks.

Comment: But how to do this? Is there any standard for using `mod_rewrite` with php?

Comment: Or it must be set up in `.htaccess`?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is a PHP mod, and it depends on the hosting company what mods are enabled by default. Chances are a quick support ticket will take care of this.

Comment: But on localhost? Im using XAMPP..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking how to do this, but it's a setting in **Settings > Permalinks**. You would select the **Day and Name** option. This should automatically format your **Post** articles in this format.